# Laravel validate arrays

Tags: laravel

My Laravel form submission has an item called invoice_products which contains all lines of invoice data.Here is what I get when I `dd($request->invoice_products)` .  It is an array of two dynamically generated forlm lines. I can have many such lines in my form. I am trying to validate each of these fields individually.

```
 [
  {
    "product_no": 3,
    "product_name": "Dolor vitae ducimus voluptatum quia.",
    "product_price": 12,
    "product_disc": 0,
    "product_qty": 1,
    "line_total": "12.00",
    "product_tax": {
      "rate": 5,
      "name": "VAT"
    },
    "line_tax_value": "0.60",    
    "product_sku": "Dr. Bailee Aufderhar MD"
  },
  {
    "product_no": 13,
    "product_name": "Esse explicabo quos ut autem iusto nam est quia.",
    "product_price": 111,
    "product_disc": 0,
    "product_qty": 1,
    "line_total": "111.00",
    "product_tax": {
      "rate": 5,
      "name": "VAT"
    },
    "line_tax_value": "5.55",    
    "product_sku": "Addie Reichert II"
  }
]
```

This is my validation code in laravel. It doesn't seem to work. What am I missing? I read in the documentation that arrays can be validated using *.

```
     $this->validate($request, [
            'invoice_products.product_sku.*' => 'required|exists:items,sku',
            'invoice_products.product_price.*' => 'required',
            'invoice_products.product_disc.*' => 'required',
            'invoice_products.product_qty.*' => 'required|numeric|min:0|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the asteric in the wrong place, try:

```
'invoice_products.*.product_sku' => ...
```

Comment: Well that's the correct syntax according to the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: Also, `invoice_products.product_rate` doesn't exist in your array. Did you mean `invoice_products.*.product_tax.rate`?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been {{invoice_products.product_price}} . My mistake.